# Filtering on Date column in ADF Dataflow

Tags: azure-data-factory

**Problem**

I want to be able to filter on the latest date in the data set. Which would normally be current month -1 as the dataset is for last month. For example, if we are in January we would be working with December 2021 dates. If we are in February 2022 we will be working with January 2022 dates.

I am using ADF dataflow for transformations and my data somewhat looks like this:

| ID | Customer | Month Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | December 2021 |
| 1 | ABC | November 2021 |
| 2 | XYZ | December 2021 |

**Output that I want**

| ID | Customer | Month Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | December 2021 |
| 2 | XYZ | December 2021 |

**What I have tried**

I have tried a few things, like passing Parameters and using Filter mapping. However none of the methods are working.

**Here's the expression I used for Filter**

```
{Month Year}==addMonths(currentDate(), -1, 'MMMM YYYY')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have repro’d in my lab and the below expression worked for me.

**Source:**

[image]

**Filter transformation:**

```
month(addMonths(currentDate(),-1)) == month(toDate({Month Year},'MMMMM yyyy'))
```

[image]

**Filter output:**

[image]

Comment: Just a small nit ... I believe you could use subMonths() here :)

Comment: @Mark Kromer MSFT, thank you! you are right, we could also use this expression, month(subMonths(currentDate(),1)) == month(toDate({Month Year},'MMMMM yyyy'))